# Как убрать белый квадрат между вертикальным и горизонтальным ScrollBar?

Tags: wpf, xaml, style

Здравствуйте, в собственном стиле образовался белый квадрат, который ни каким способом не получается убрать, после того, как добавил `Horizontal ScrollBar`. Как заменить его на конкретный цвет или картинку? Читал, что есть возможность его удалить и на том месте будет использоваться стиль окна, но это может привести к непоправимым ошибкам.

[image: ScrollBarWhiteRectangle]

Возможно что-то было пропущено в коде:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
                <Border CornerRadius="4"  BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="0.25">
                    <Border.Background>
                        <SolidColorBrush Color="Black" Opacity="0.1"/>
                    </Border.Background>
                    <Grid x:Name="GridScrollBar" Width="8" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Track x:Name="PART_Track" Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Vertical" IsDirectionReversed="True">
                            <Track.Thumb>
                                <Thumb Style="{DynamicResource ThumbScrollBar}"/>
                            </Track.Thumb>
                            <Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                                <RepeatButton x:Name="DecreaseRepeatButton" Command="ScrollBar.PageUpCommand" Style="{DynamicResource RepeatButtonPageScrollBar}"/>
                            </Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                            <Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                                <RepeatButton x:Name="IncreaseRepeatButton" Command="ScrollBar.PageDownCommand" Style="{DynamicResource RepeatButtonPageScrollBar}"/>
                            </Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                        </Track>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="Orientation" Value="Horizontal">
                        <Setter Property="LayoutTransform" TargetName="GridScrollBar">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <RotateTransform Angle="-90"/>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                        <Setter TargetName="PART_Track" Property="Orientation" Value="Vertical"/>
                        <Setter Property="Command" Value="ScrollBar.LineRightCommand" TargetName="IncreaseRepeatButton"/>
                        <Setter Property="Command" Value="ScrollBar.LineLeftCommand" TargetName="DecreaseRepeatButton"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

`TreeViewItem`

```
     <Border Style="{StaticResource dialog_open_file_border_treeview}">
            <TreeView x:Name="treeview_directories" Style="{StaticResource dialog_open_file_treeview}" SelectedItemChanged="treeview_directories_SelectedItemChanged">
                <TreeView.Resources>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                        <Style.Setters>
                            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="3"/>
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                            <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                            <Image Name="img"  Width="20" Height="20" Stretch="Fill"
                                                   Source="{Binding
                                                   RelativeSource={RelativeSource
                                                   Mode=FindAncestor,
                                                   AncestorType={x:Type TreeViewItem}},
                                                   Path=Header,
                                                   Converter={x:Static local:HeaderToImageConverter.Instance}}"/>
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Margin="5 2 0 0"/>
                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Style.Setters>
                    </Style>
                </TreeView.Resources>
            </TreeView>
        </Border>
```

`TreeView`

```
       <Style x:Key="dialog_open_file_treeview" TargetType="{x:Type TreeView}">
    <Style.Setters>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="4"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Transparent"/>
    </Style.Setters>
</Style>
```

Comment: Проблема не в этом коде. Белый квадрат не принадлежит ни одному из скроллбаров. Проблема в контроле, который содержит скроллбары (TreeView?). Вы стилизовали его? Дайте его ControlTemplate.

Comment: Обновил и добавил TreeViewItem

Comment: Не, нужен не `TreeViewItem`, а сам `TreeView` (`StaticResource dialog_open_file_treeview`). Кстати, вы знали, что можно стиль для `TreeViewItem`'а положить в ресурсы стиля для `TreeView`?

Comment: Добавил тот самый `TreeView` (`StaticResource dialog_open_file_treeview`), как я понял, он не стилизован, чем нужно дополнить этот файл ? Да, но как это сделать ?

Comment: Может быть, подойдёт просто выставить Background?

Comment: Убрал и изменял цвет, всё так же остается белый квадрат.

Comment: Хм, а если подложить под него другой цвет? Например, так: `<Grid Background="Green"><TreeView ...></Green>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используя выше упомянутый `TreeViewItem` нужно дополнить строчкой 
`<ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">` после `Border`.
Также нужно добавить такой код, который будет в сочетание с `ScrollBar`:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}" BasedOn="{x:Null}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
                <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <ScrollContentPresenter Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" 
                                            ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" CanContentScroll="{TemplateBinding CanContentScroll}"/>
                    <ScrollBar Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedHorizontalScrollBarVisibility}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" 
                               x:Name="PART_HorizontalScrollBar" Orientation="Horizontal" Value="{Binding Path=HorizontalOffset, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                               ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportWidth}" Minimum="0" Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableWidth}" AutomationProperties.AutomationId="HorizontalScrollBar"/>
                    <ScrollBar Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" 
                               x:Name="PART_VerticalScrollBar" Orientation="Vertical" Value="{Binding Path=VerticalOffset, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" 
                               ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportHeight}" Minimum="0" Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableHeight}" AutomationProperties.AutomationId="VerticalScrollBar"/>
                    <Border Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Background="Transparent"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: О, класс! Но вы уверены насчёт `Background="Transparent"` для `Border`?

Comment: В моем случае можно вообще удалить эту строчку, все остается также . Если уже кто-то возьмёт этот код чисто, как `ScrollViewer`,то это строчка возможно поможет.

Comment: А, понял: фон задаётся во внешнем Grid'е. Очень хорошо.